# Using react-image-crop cropping the zoom in image

Tags: reactjs, react-image, react-image-crop

I am using react-image-crop for cropping the image and I have implemented the zoom on the image. now I want to crop the Zooomed in image but when I try to crop the image it crops the original image, not the zoomed-in image.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your progress? It would help us troubleshoot the problem and help you with it.